# Open new page, deserialize object in GWT

Tags: java, ajax, gwt, gwt-rpc

I need to open new page and pass to this page object. New page will be handled by servlet. Please, tell me, how can pass object to servlet? Note, that this servlet will write content directly to new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard way of doing this is to issue a RPC request once the page is loaded. If you want to pass these data without additional RPC, you can pre-serialize the data into javascript variable. The most difficult for understanding part is serialization itself but these two articles give quite good insight on this:

1. http://www.techhui.com/profiles/blogs/simpler-and-speedier-gwt-with
2. http://wiki.shiftyjelly.com/index.php/GWT

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I solved my problem in such way: 1) created Map bean in spring 2) on client, i generated uuid token, passed uuid with object via RPC 3) put received object to Map on server 4) on client, opened new page, passed token there 5) retreived object by token on servlet. Thank you very much!